# Gerar um conjunto de números em php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, banco-de-dados

Amigos preciso gerar automaticamente uma sequencia de numeros e separalos por virgula em php, exemplo.
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 guardar em uma variavel e depois fazer um insert em um banco mysql.

mais ou menos assim.

INSERT INTO tabela (n_serie, ano, numeros)

INSERT INTO remessaoff(ano_blocos, conjunto_blocos, intervalo_bloco) VALUES (A2, 2020, aqui os numeros gerados );

Comment: Leia sobre as funções `join` e `range`.

Answer (score 1):

**FUNÇÃO range()** - retorna uma sequência conforme os parâmetros por nós definidos.

```
//retorna uma matriz de elementos de "1" a "12"
$numeros = range(1,12);
```

**resultado**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 )
```

---

---

**FUNÇÃO join ()** - retorna uma string dos elementos de uma matriz.

```
$numeros = range(1,12);

echo join(",",$numeros);
```

**Resultado**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

[**Exemplo funcional - Ideone**](https://ideone.com/ytrbdb)

Comment: excelente, deu certo aqui. muito obrigado.

Comment: @WELLINGTONLEITE, não precisa agradecer, quando alguma resposta resolver seu problema marque-a como aceita veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png